# FontAwesome icons doesn't get displayed on Android App

Tags: java, android, user-interface, font-awesome, genymotion

I have used FontAwesome for icons in my app. Specifically in some TextViews. Since I want that in some particular text views, I made a custom Text View.

```
public class FontAwesomeTextView extends TextView {

    public FontAwesomeTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public FontAwesomeTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
        super(context, attributeSet);
    }

    public FontAwesomeTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet, int style) {
        super(context, attributeSet, style);
    }

    @Override
    public void setTypeface(Typeface tf, int style) {
        String fontPath = "fonts/fontawesome.ttf";
        Typeface typeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), fontPath);
        this.setTypeface(typeFace);
    }
}
```

When I use this and add a Close icon, it gets displayed perfectly on Genymotion emulator with API 18, but when I run the app on my phone with API 21, they doesn't get displayed correctly or it displays crosses.

What causes this error? Any fixes?

---

#### Fixed

The issue was with the API. Android 5.0.x is known to have this issue. As the below answers mention, fix it by converting the TTf to OTF. (Might not work in some situations still.) Android 5.1.x is known to have fixed this.

Comment: Can you post code where you set the typeface/text? Do the icons display correctly on a Genymotion image running Api 18?

Comment: @fractalwrench Hello, I found the fix. It's posted as an answer below. Thanks though. :)

Answer (score 2):

In version of Lollipop before 5.1,some custom fonts loaded using the API `Typeface.createFromAsset()` do not render with the correct font. This issue was fixed with the release of Android 5.1, but can still affect your app users running Android `Lollipop 5.0.x.`

Please try out converting your ".TTF" file to ".OTF" file. In my case it helped me to resolve this issue.